# Duplicate: XPath expressions with default namespace

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, odata

I'm currently writing a C# class that allows me to construct entities from an OData feed.
Don't ask why, I just need it at the moment :)

The snippet of the XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<entry xml:base="http://demo.tenforce.acc/Api.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <id>http://demo.tenforce.acc/Api.svc/Items(387)</id>
  <title type="text"></title>
  <updated>2011-09-22T07:35:54Z</updated>
  <author>
    <name />
  </author>
  <link rel="edit" title="Item" href="Items(387)" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Children" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Children" href="Items(387)/Children" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Parent" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Parent" href="Items(387)/Parent" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Attachments" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Attachments" href="Items(387)/Attachments" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Predecessors" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Predecessors" href="Items(387)/Predecessors" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Successors" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Successors" href="Items(387)/Successors" />
  <category term="TenForce.Execution.Api2.Objects.Item" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
  <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
      <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">387</d:Id>
    </m:properties>
  </content>
</entry>
```

I've created a code snippet that loads the entire xml string into an XmlDocument, and generates a XmlNamespaceManager as well to have access to the various namespaces.

I'm trying to select the `<category>` element from the XML but I can't seem to get the Xpath expression right. I've tried the following:

- //entry/category
- descendant::xmlns:cateogry
- //d:category
- //m:category
- //category
- //xml:category

But none seem to be selected the node in question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting nodes with the default namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008930/selecting-nodes-with-the-default-namespace)

Comment: another duplicate [Using Xpath With Default Namespace in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585812/using-xpath-with-default-namespace-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh never mind, i've found the solution.
I had to add the namespace for the atom elements....

```
var manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(_mDocument.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("d", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices");
manager.AddNamespace("m", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata");
manager.AddNamespace("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
```

This allowed me to select the `<category>` element by using //atom:category